# Paypal sandbox negative testing not working

Tags: paypal-sandbox

I have set up negative testing for an account then set the error code desired as the Transaction Amount Field for example 106.06 to invoke error code 10606 "Buyer cannot pay” no errors  are returned the order is processed.

If I try another error code 10539 “This transaction cannot be processed”. An error is return and the order is not processed.

I am using the The US site error codes: http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/PP_APIReference/Appx-ErrorCodes_and_Messages.html and we are in Australia are these the correct error codes?

Any ideas what is causing this? Is this the correct way to use Negative Testing in the sandbox?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late but I stumbled across the answer for me.

You didn't specify the API Name you are working with `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` and according to [Paypal's Negative Testing Docs](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_error-conditions/) we are supposed to use an `AMT` field and

> To trigger an error condition on an amount-related field, specify a error code value as a number with two digits to the right of the decimal point. For example, specify a value of 107.55 to trigger the 10755 error.

I found their information to be completely false!  What I finally got working was to use `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT` and NOT use a decimal.

So here is what I came up with

```
USER={yourUID}&
PWD={yourPSWD}&
SIGNATURE={yourSig}&
TOKEN={yourToken}&
METHOD=DoExpressCheckoutPayment&
VERSION=119&
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=10486
```

**Edit**:
I later found a better option specifically for the Payment Method Refused (10486) that I mentioned above. Take a look: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec_fundingfailure10486/#testing-saleorauth

Comment: SHOCK HORROR: I found their information to be completely false!